# Using SES SDK to send email from python 2.7 on Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to build a lambda function using python 2.7 ( using boto3). I need to use AWS SDK to trigger the ses email. I will be sending to, email_subject, email_body as the arguments to this function. This function in turn should use the aws access key Id and aws secrete access key which would have permissions to trigger emails from the already verified domain and verified email id.

I am looking for a way to specify aws credentials -

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ses')
.....  < how to mention credentials before calling send_email function ? >
response = client.send_email( ...... )
```

Comment: So this question has nothing to do with SES, you just need to know how to specify credentials to Boto3? You could always start by reading the documentation: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html Or since you are running this code on Lambda, just give the Lambda function the appropriate IAM permissions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero research effort, and the answer is given in very specific detail in the AWS SDK documentation.

Comment: I see you didn't read the page I linked to. Also, using IAM permissions as I suggested is actually the recommended way to provide credentials to the AWS SDK.

Comment: @user3101836 if those are real credentials you should remove that comment, this is the internet

Comment: @nthall - These were temp. credentials, dumping them already. But thanks :)